# JBoss 7.1 - struts1 - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jboss, struts

I have the following error on my jsp page and do not where to look.

```
     javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:858)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:791)
    org.apache.jsp.jsp.layout.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:179)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1054)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:292)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:268)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:329)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:229)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1858)
    nl.kb.idm.selfservice.Servlet.process(Servlet.java:145)
    nl.kb.idm.selfservice.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:90)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    nl.kb.idm.selfservice.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:42)
    nl.kb.idm.selfservice.CrossScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossScriptingFilter.java:40)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    ...
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Kind regards,
Jo

Comment: Without code, no one would be able to help you..

Comment: Show please your `layout.jsp` - exception is happened when this JSP tries to include some other resource

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of bugs can be tricky to track down. One thing that you can do is wrap the whole page in an exception handler like this:

```
<%
try {
%>

<!-- Your HTML and page logic here -->

<%
} catch(Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

Make sure that it doesn't make it into production though, as all the exceptions from that page will go to your stderr, rather than your logs.

Hope that helps!